# How to decide when QEMU quest is able to process packets?

Tags: linux, networking, qemu

I'm using QEMU with `tap` interfaces on the host in order to provide connectivity to the guests.

I'm now trying to figure out a mechanism of deciding when a guest has successfully booted and is ready to process packets.

Is it safe to assume that when the `tap` interface on the host switches state to `RUNNING` the guest network interface driver loaded the interface for use and is able to receive traffic?